# How do I hide the navigation view when the webview is tapped? [iphone]

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I want to hide and show the top navigation controller when the webview that is containing it is tapped. How do I listen to the webview?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question here but can you not just call this?

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: Yes, I could. But I want to listen to the webview and get the tap on it

Comment: Gotcha. Try throwing on a gesture recognizer and put in an If statement.